# Sharing to Twitter in iOS 11 without intrusive requests

Tags: ios, swift, twitter

I have a simple iOS game where the player should have the ability to share his score on twitter. I was initially going to use SLServiceTypeTwitter, but found out it is now deprecated on iOS 11.

Therefore, my only other option is to use Twitter's API. I did so, and I encountered another problem:

[image]

It is prompting the user to connect their accounts to my application, which seems very intrusive. Is there any easier way to share Twitter content in a more passive way?

Comment: Did you get an easy solution to your problem?
I also want to just share to Twitter from my app.

Comment: @Somal I did not. I ended up using Instagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably stuck with Twitter's API if you want to post automatically.

Otherwise, the simplest solution would be to use something like Apple's [UIActivityViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityviewcontroller).

Comment: Already using UIActivityViewController, but it is not as direct for Twitter